# What does 鲜明 mean?

Tags: meaning

I looked it up in more than 3 dictionaries, but I still have trouble understanding it. Please use some other ways other than dictionaries to explain it. Thank you so much in advance. An example sentence with it:
……给读者留下鲜明深刻的印象……

Comment: You might need to add what really makes it so hard to understand in your question? The dictionary definition is pretty clear actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applied to colors, it means something like brightly colored, therefore it "stands out" and so "eye-catching".

When applied in another context, like in 印象, it means something like "distinctive", or "distinct", as in "a distinctive impression" because anybody who "stands out" of the crowd, (for example dressed up like a brightly colored peacock), would leave a distinctive / distinct impression. An acceptable paraphrase would be "an unforgettable / memorable impression"

Perhaps @imkzh used "deep" is because of the presence of 深刻, which means "deep" in the abstract sense of being "profound", not deep as in "the deep blue sea".

So, one could say 鲜明深刻的印象 would be translated as "a deeply profound / distinct impression"?

Answer (score 0):

鲜：vivid

明：bright

鲜明：分明而确定 clear-cut and well-defined.

or simply:

> 给读者留下鲜明深刻的印象
>
> leaving readers a **DEEP** impression.

鲜明 could also be used literally to describe color:

> 鲜明的色彩
>
> some color that is bright and vivid.

Comment: You translated it to "leaving readers a DEEP impression.". I still don't get the meaning of 鲜明, because 鲜明 has nothing to do with DEEP.

Comment: @KevinWhite i have mentioned `鲜明：分明而确定 clear-cut and well-defined.` in my answer.